# Selenium file upload - invalid locator

Tags: javascript, selenium

I've the following form where I would like to upload a file.

```
            <div class="ChooseFile" data-flu="name2" data-target="[preview-container-text-bulk]" data-file-template="uploadCard" data-error-target="[data-upload-error-text-bulk]" data-type="txt" data-context="bulkImport" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Fileup">
                <button class="custom-style-fileIOBtn">Choose File</button>
                <input type="file" class="fileCntr" name="fileinput2" style="display:none;">
            </div>
            <div class="customLogo phn" id="EA-Blk-Invite-Filetext">
                <h5>No file selected</h5>
            </div>
```

I tried to locate the upload function with differen selectors:

```
xpath://div[@id='EA-Blk-Invite-Upload']
css:#EA-Blk-Invite-Upload
id:EA-Blk-Invite-Fileup
className:custom-style-fileIOBtn
```

```
    //Upload file with user's email list
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("#EA-Blk-Invite-Upload")));
    console.log(`\nElement wait`);
    await driver.findElement(until.elementLocated(By.css("#EA-Blk-Invite-Upload")));
    console.log(`\nElement located`);
    await driver.sendKeys(process.cwd() + '/bulkInvite.txt');
    console.log(`\nFile uploaded`);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
-- Login name & password submitted

Element wait

ERROR: Unable to invite users
TypeError: Invalid locator
```

Comment: Selenium can only upload files to `<input>` elements using sendKeys.  The problem you have is Selenium won't interact with invisible elements, as denoted by the `style="display:none;"`. You can use the `executeScript()` to make it visible again.

Comment: Thanks @Harry King for pointing me in the right direction!